# Get iframe by message event

Tags: javascript, iframe, postmessage

I have several iframes with same origin (but different pathnames) on the page.
Every iframe emits `message` event through `postMessage`.
Parent window listens these events:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  /* Get iframe element by event */
});
```

I want to get source iframe element for every event.
The important limitation is that I have no access to `event.source.contentWindow` because of cross-origin.
**UPD: answer below**

Comment: What about `event.target`? Is it the iframe?

Comment: would event.source or event.origin help?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda `event.target` seems to be the parent window. It can be understood from `event.target.location.href`

Comment: @epascarello `event.origin` doesn't help because all frames have the same origin. Only pathnames are different

Comment: @Legotin Try using `event.target.url` to get the url from where the postMessage was fired. If that's not what you're looking for, then I don't understand the question.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda okay, I say it again :) `event.target` refers to the parent window

Comment: Ah okay, you should use `event.target` instead

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/facebook/000/335/554/cce.png

Comment: *"The important limitation is that I have no access to event.source.contentWindow because of cross-origin."* If you don't own the other website, how do you arrange the code being sent or received to and from the iframes? Post Message still requires access to both sides at least upon creation of said endpoints.

Comment: @zer00ne this post message is arranged by third-party developers

Answer (score 18):

The solution is to compare `event.source` and `iframe.contentWindow`:

```
function getFrameByEvent(event) {
  return [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')).filter(function(iframe) {
    return iframe.contentWindow === event.source;
  })[0];
}
```

Here's more modern version:

```
function getFrameByEvent(event) {
  return Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')).filter(iframe => {
    return iframe.contentWindow === event.source;
  })[0];
}
```

Comment: I am getting an exception when I do this: `Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

Comment: @AlfredoEstebanHernndezDvalo the answer is the solution ^

Comment: Hi @Legotin thanks for reply, I'm getting the same error than Tamas,   Uncaught `DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.` Any idea how to solve that?